# Using .ico file for cursor

Tags: css, cross-browser

Can I use an .ico in the css cursor property without consequences (i.e full browser compatibility.) or must I use a .cur?

As in:

```
cursor: url(img/cursor.ico);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cur` files and `ico` files are almost identical. The only important difference is that the cur file has a hotspot at the tip of the icon.

You should find that both work identically over the web.